# Limit of quantized entropy

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory

Consider the continuous random variable $X \in \mathbb R$ and the deterministic function $Y = f(X)$, $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. For the conditional entropy we have
$$H(Y|X) = 0.$$
Does this imply
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} H(Y^{(n)}|X^{(n)}) = 0$$
where $Y^{(n)}$ and $X^{(n)}$ are quantized versions of $Y$ and $X$ that become increasingly finer with larger $n$?

I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} H(Y^{(n)}) = H(Y)$ but I don't know if this applies to the conditional case, too. Thanks!

Comment: is this a home work?

Comment: no, it is a question that came up during my thesis.